# Join Query C# SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm developing on visual Studio using asp.net core and Entity Framework.

This is my query

```
var Male = from s in _context.ApprovalKits 
           join r in _context.Registrations on s.StundetId equals r.StundetId into a
           where s.RoomType.Equals(RoomType.s)
                  && s.HealthCondition.Equals(HealthCondition.none)
                  && r.gender.Equals(Gender.m)
           select a;
```

There is an error on the `r.gender`:

> The name 'r' does not exist in the current context

How can I fix my query?

Comment: Try `a.gender.Equals(Gender.m)`

Comment: It is not clear to me if you really intended to do a group join or just a join, [does the documentation for group join help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause#group-join) ?

Answer (score 1):

If your EF Entities have Associations set-up correctly then you should never need to use manual Joins in Linq because you can simply do this:

```
List<Registration> maleRegistrations = db.Registrations
    .Include( r => r.ApprovalKit )
    .Where( r => r.ApprovalKit.RoomType == RoomType.S )
    .Where( r => r.HealthCondition == HealthCondition.None )
    .Where( r => r.Gender == Gender.Male );
    .ToList();
```

(You can also consolidate the `Where`, like so:)

```
List<Registration> maleRegistrations = db.Registrations
    .Include( r => r.ApprovalKit )
    .Where( r =>
        r.ApprovalKit.RoomType == RoomType.S &&
        r.HealthCondition == HealthCondition.None &&
        r.Gender == Gender.Male
    )
    .ToList();
```